# How to simplify this boolean / tenary expression?

Tags: javascript, boolean, boolean-expression

How would I simplify this ternary expression?

```
c = a === false && b === false ? true : false;
```

`c` is `true` only when `a` and `b` are `false`.

Comment: `c = a === false && b === false;`

Comment: could be as simple as `c = !a && !b;` depending on the data

Comment: @Carcigenicate strict checker

Comment: @epascarello is this !a && !b; not equal to !( a && b) ?

Comment: @LarryS.: Yes, those are equivalent, according to [De Morgan's laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws).

Comment: @ScottSauyet isn't that `!(a || b)`

Comment: @adiga: Well, d'oh!  Yes -- I swear that's what I read in the comment!  The simple rule is don't comment before caffeine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need ternary expression here. The first expression itself returns are Boolean

```
c = a === false && b === false
```

Another trick you can use is compare `a !== false` with `b`

```
c = a !== false === b
```

Here there are only two values to check. If there are more values then its better use every method.

```
c = [a,b].every(x => x === false)
```

Comment: Not only is `c = a !== false === b` an ugly, unreadable trick, it's also wrong.  When `a` and `b` are both `true`, this sets `c` to`true`, where the original would set it to `false`.

Comment: @ScottSauyet my acceptable answer would be this c = a === false && b === false. this c = a !== false === b looks fancy, but the readability was hurting my head :)